# How do I send parameters to Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, routes

I have doctors and doctor_country_city table.

```
Schema::create('doctors', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('doctor_no')->unique();
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->string('fullname')->unique();
        $table->string('profile_image')->nullable();
        $table->date('birthday')->nullable();
        $table->enum('gender', ['male', 'female'])->nullable();
        $table->string('phone');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('website_url')->nullable();
        $table->smallInteger('starting_month')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->year('starting_year')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->dateTime('sort_date');
        $table->softDeletes();
    });


Schema::create('doctor_country_city', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('doctor_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('country_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('city_id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('doctor_id')->references('id')->on('doctors');
        $table->foreign('country_id')->references('country_id')->on('cities');
        $table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');
    });
```

I would like to send multiple parameters to the route. What should my controller file and model relationship be like?

```
Example: Route::get('{country?}/{city?}/{slug?}', 'DoctorsController@showDoctor');
```

Comment: Why do you want send it using get method, Why not use post method.

Comment: Please do some research before asking a question. You can find everything in de documentation of laravel. for example https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests

Comment: I suggest you read different methods and how you could communicate with each. e.g. GET is used to query the resources with query params, POST is used to create the resource being payload provided, PUT is used to update the resource, DELETE is used to remove the resource. So, use wisely each of the methods as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Before giving you the solution I'd suggest you to rethink your database design.

Can a doctor belong to many cities? If not you don't need the `doctor_country_city` pivot table in the first place. Also you shouldn't relate the doctor to a city and a country as well. That's quite weird because your database potentially allows to assign a doctor to New York, France. A city by definition belongs to one country only.

So I'd rather relate a doctor to a city which is related to a country.

`Dr. John Doe > New York > USA`

That makes more sense to me. So you'll have one more table called `countries` and their models will have relationships like so:

```
class Doctor extends Model {
   public function city() {
      return $this->belongsTo(City::class);
   }
}

class City extends Model {
   public function country() {
      return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
   }
   public function doctors() {
      return $this->hasMany(Doctor::class);
   }
}

class Country extends Model {
   public function cities() {
      return $this->hasMany(City::class);
   }
}
```

One country can have many cities, but one city belongs to one country. One city can have many doctors, but a doctor belongs to one city only.

For further information about eloquent relationships [check the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships).

Going to your question, I suppose that's a GET request where you want to get all doctors from a given city. There are many ways to achieve that.

You can use a [scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#query-scopes), using the `whereHas` Eloquent method. This method allows to filter your Doctor model results by a value in a related table.

I don't want to write down all the code for you. I encourage you to read the documentation about the tools I listed above.